# Correct import on bring header xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

im working with swift3 in IOS and library https://github.com/gpolak/LFHeatMap,
when I create my bring header:

```
//
//  MocaAdmin-Bridging-Header.h
//  MocaAdmin
//

#import <LFHeatMap/LFHeatMap.h>
```

[image]

But when I try to compile, Xcode show me:

[image]

What Im doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Have you added $(SRCROOT)/ Before project name ?

Comment: In what item? into the build options

Comment: Yes . to set accurate path till project directory. If it still not correct then check header file info for its correct path . all we doing here is giving path of header file.

Comment: Compare header file path with the path generated in objective c bridge header after adding srcroot.